# Error message when referring to the value of a part of one element in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages

The following works fine to define an element of a two-argument list:

```
T[1, 2] = {3, 4, "yes"}
```

But when I try to change the third part, like this

```
T[1, 2][[3]] = "no"
```

I get the error message

```
Set::setps: T[1,2] in the part assignment is not a symbol.
```

The same message also appears if I go

```
If[T[1,2][[3]] == "yes", Print["hello"]]
```

The program doesn't print "hello". It goes

```
Set::setps: T[1,2] in the part assignment is not a symbol.
```

I am not an advanced user. What is the simplest way to change this part, so that T[1,2], which was originally {3,4,"yes"} changes to {3,4,"no"}; or to refer to it in the first part of an If statement?

Comment: `T[1,2]` is not a symbol.
From the documentation: "Part assignments are implemented only for parts of the value of a symbol."
Use `ReplacePart[T[1,2],3->"No"]` for example.

Comment: @ciao - Thanks for this. It gets rid of the error message, and `T[1, 2] = {3, 4, "yes"}; ReplacePart[T[1, 2], 3 -> "No"]` yields `{3, 4, "no"}`. But `T[1, 2] = {3, 4, "yes"}; ReplacePart[T[1, 2], 3 -> "No"]; T[1, 2]` yields `{3, 4, "yes"}`. It's as if it only works momentarily. Edit: ah, I get it now: `ReplacePart[]` is an expression, so I should go `T[1, 2] = {3, 4, "yes"}; T[1, 2]=ReplacePart[T[1, 2], 3 -> "No"]`. That works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own function:

```
ClearAll[setPart];
SetAttributes[setPart, HoldAll];
setPart[Part[x_, part__], y_] := x = ReplacePart[x, {part} -> y];

tt[1, 2] = {1, 2, "yes"};

setPart[tt[0, 2][[3]], "no"];

tt[0, 2]
```

> ```
> (*  {1, 2, "no"}  *)
> ```

You could use a symbol with no built-in meaning:

```
ClearAll[LeftArrow];
SetAttributes[LeftArrow, HoldAll];
LeftArrow[Part[x_, part__], y_] := x = ReplacePart[x, {part} -> y];

tt[1, 2] = {1, 2, "yes"};

tt[1, 2][[3]] ← "no";

tt[1, 2]
```

> ```
> (*  {1, 2, "no"}  *)
> ```

`LeftArrow` (`←`) can be entered with <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd><</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>ESC</kbd>.